# AlertDialog not displaying from Inner Class

Tags: java, android

I've got a class inside my MainActivity class from which I'm trying to display an AlertDialog. The Dialog isn't showing and there are no errors. The code for the dialog is:

```
AlertDialog.builder builder = new AlertDialog.builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setMessage("Unkown Game Code. please try again.").setTitle("Game Code Error").setNeutralButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    finish();
  }
}
builder.create().show();
```

Comment: When/how is this code triggered?

Comment: It's triggered when a message is received via a WebSocket. I know for a fact the code is running because I put some logs right before and after the shown code that runs.

Comment: but is the activity visible(foreground) when the code is triggered? or the message is received via service or some background thread?

Comment: Yes, the activity is visible.

Comment: You have to show more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code is triggered when you receive a message via WebSocket, it might probably be async.
Try and run your code in your Activitys main Thread:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      //Your Code
   }
});
```

Comment: This was indeed the solution. It's interesting to see that Android's debugging and error messages don't actually explain the issue.